# Porque o MongoDB (nodejs + mongoose) não atualiza propriedade de objeto de um documento?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho um documento (dados do MongoDB) de **user** que tem um campo **tags** que armazena as tags ja usada pelo usuario. É um array de objeto no formato `{text: 'tag1', count: 0}`. O problema é ao atualizar os dados o valor das propriedades dos objetos permanecem os antigos, mesmo que no console.log mostre os novos valores.

Pego o usuario especifico com: `users.findOne({name: 'exemplo'})`

Exemplo 1: Funciona se eu fizer isso.

```js
user.tags = []
await user.save()
//No caso, definindo as tags para um array vazio
```

Exemplo 2: Funciona se eu fizer isso.

```js
user.tags = [{text: 'tag1', count: 0}, {text: 'tag2', count: 0}]
await user.save()
// Colocando um array real, atualiza normalmente.
```

Exemplo 3: **NÃO funciona** se eu fizer isso (o valor continua 0 zero)

```js
user.tags[0].count = 5
await user.save()
/** Se eu fizer um console.log(user.tags) depois que salvar o count da posição zero mostra como 5 (correto), mas no banco de dados continua 0, nao atualiza */
//Ou seja, no console.log mostra certo, mas no DB nao
```

Exemplo 4: **Só o incremento nao funciona** se eu fizer isso (o valor continua 0 zero)

```js
// valor atual de user.tags = [{text: 'tag1', count: 0}, {text: 'tag2', count: 0}]
user.tags = [{text: 'tag1', count: 1}, {text: 'tag2', count: 0}, {text: 'tag3', count: 0}]
/** Repare que agora a tag1 tem o count como 1, antes era zero. E agora tem a tag3, nesse exemplo a tag3 é adicionada significando que esta funcionando, mas o count da tag1 continua como zero */
// Não entendo porque nao muda ja que estou colocando um novo array completo
await user.save()
```

**A "solução"** que eu econtrei foi uma gambiarra apagando todo array e colocando o novo. Mas até agora não entendi porque eu preciso apagar para adicionar o novo array.

```js
// solução na gambiarra
user.tags = []
user.tags = [{text: 'tag1', count: 1}, {text: 'tag2', count: 0}, {text: 'tag3', count: 0}]
await user.save()
```

ModelSchema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, min: 3},
    tags: { type: Array },
)

const modelName = 'users'

if (mongoose.connection && mongoose.connection.models[modelName]) {
    module.exports = mongoose.connection.models[modelName]
} else {
    module.exports = mongoose.model(modelName, modelSchema)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Os *Documents* do Mongoose utilizam *setters* para identificar quais campos do seu documento foram mutados, e optimizam o update no banco de dados para não enviar mais do que o necessário.

Se o `count` não está sendo atualizado no banco de dados, é porque ele não possui um *setter*, provavelmente decorrente de como você declarou esse *Schema*/*Model*.

É possível marcar manualmente que um campo foi alterado com o método `markModified`:

```
user.tags[0].count = 5;
user.markModified('tags');
await user.save();
```

Porém trabalhar com um *setter* devidamente configurado deve ser preferível.

Para isso, ao invés de simplesmente declarar `tags` como sendo do tipo *Array*, crie um *Schema* específico para essa propriedade:

```
const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: { type: String },
    number: { type: Number },
);

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, min: 3 },
    tags: { type: [TagSchema] },
);
```

Comment: adicionei como esta o schema, tem mais campos, como senha e outos. Mas a estrutura principal é essa. Como faria essa configuração no schema?

Comment: @DhenysonJhean, veja se a informação que eu adicionei te ajuda.

Comment: Ajudou sim, muito obrigado. Não sabia que poderia declarar um schema dentro de outro.